# Average Distance for Unit Ball

Tags: integration, average

> Let $B$ be a unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Find the average distance from points in $B$ to the origin.

My progress: If I am not mistaken, this problem should be solved by triple integrals and the function should be $x^2+y^2+z^2$ with division by area of unit ball. But I am unsure on which constraints should we construct that triple integral? Any help or suggestion would be welcomed!

Comment: Is the ball solid or hollow?

Comment: I think it should be solid.

Comment: The function should be the distance from the centre, which in rectangular coordinates is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, and you should divide by the volume of the ball. But it’s probably easiest to do it in spherical coordinates. See, for instance, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235940/average-distance-from-a-point-in-a-sphere-to-the-origin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler approach is integrating over distance from the origin. We can write our integral as $\frac1V\int rdS$, where $dS$ represents the surface area of the hollow sphere of a given radius. In other words, $dS = 4\pi r^2dr$. So, our integral is $$\frac1V\int\limits_0^14\pi r^3dr=3\int\limits_0^1r^3dr=\frac34r^4\bigg\vert_0^1=\frac34$$